# sync local folder to github repo with ubuntu

Tags: linux, github, synchronization

Im an noob on github.
I have an repo in github.com
No i have downloaded it and write some new files and edit some files.
Now i want to sync this folder to my Guthub repo.
But how i can do that? Can anyone help me please step by step?

i have read something here but i cant undersand how it works.
i tryed some codes but it dosent work :/

How i can use this:

```
git remote add origin 'url to github repo'
```

git pull origin master
git checkout master
git cherry-pick 
git commit -m 'Made a change to the master branch'
git push origin master

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't cloned a github repo, you have to connect it to your remote repo with:

```
git remote add origin <url_of_your_github_repo>
```

To 'sync' your local changes, add the files you want to send to your changes list with:

```
git add <filename>
```

Then, when you have added all your files, commit them:

```
git commit -m "Commit message : new project begun"
```

It will add your files into the HEAD, but not to your remote repo yet. In order to do this, you will have to do:

```
git push origin <origin>
```

where origin is generally master.

After doing this, you can check on your github account that a new commit has been made.

To make things easier, when you begin a new project, you can create a new repo on github, then clone it on your computer with:

```
git clone <url_of_your_github_repo>
```

So that you won't need to connect your local repo to the remote one.

Comment: Thank you for your post!  Is it possible to sync the Folder? Your write: [code]git add <filename>[/code] but if i have to commit each file it takes a lot of time and then i can edit the files ob githubs website :/

Comment: To sync the whole folder, you can add all the files:

Comment: To sync the whole folder, you can add all the files: `git add *` or `git add .`, then commit and finally push like shown before

Comment: It is maybe a trivial step, but I would add the first command `git init` in order to make initial local folder versioned by git. Otherwise you cannot run the other commands.